# Crontab does not run on CentOS 7

Tags: cron, centos7

I'm using CentOS 7, and installed "cronie"

```
yum install cronie
```

I have a shell to backup my home folder, shell's content (of course, backup.sh is 775)

```
#!/bin/bash
#START
TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M`          
FILENAME=backupHome_123.30.150.29_$TIME.tar.gz 
SRCDIR=/home                    
DESDIR=/backup            
tar -cpvzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
#END
```

And add to crontab -e

```
00 2 * * * /bin/bash /backup/backup.sh
```

But crontab does nothing. When I check log at /var/log/cron only, something like that and no more error or processing log

```
May  1 00:26:08 app crontab[12041]: (root) END EDIT (root)
May  1 00:33:21 app crontab[12086]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
May  1 00:34:25 app crontab[12086]: (root) END EDIT (root)
```

Anyone can give me some advises to make crontab work?
Thank you.

Comment: You set `2:00 AM` for taking backup.

Comment: Where exactly is your script? Is it really in `/backup/backup.sh`? Note crontab needs full paths.

Comment: @AliYousefiSabzevar, yes, I want to run backup at 2AM every day.

Comment: @fedorqui /backup/backup.sh is full path :) at / I create backup folder, so, full path is /backup/backup.sh :)

Answer (score 7):

I found that the most useful information was actually given by

```
systemctl status crond
```

Which revealed that it failed to load correctly due to an "Unauthorized SELinux context" error.

Answer (score 5):

You want to make sure cron is started & that it is started if your server reboots so you need two commands on CentOS 7 to make sure of this:

```
systemctl enable crond && systemctl restart crond
```

If you are used to using sudo, you can add sudo in front of above command. like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable crond && systemctl restart crond
```

YOU WILL get confirmation from system, something like:

> Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/crond.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service.

Then lastly check cron is running
pgrep cron

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if cron daemon isn't running.
Check it with:

```
pgrep cron
```

If command returns nothing, run:

```
systemctl restart crond
```

This should help.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm late to answer you, but maybe someone will have this kind of problem. It is possible that CRON can't run the script because the path is not correct.

Your path is

```
00 2 * * * /bin/bash /backup/backup.sh
```

I guess that path should be:

```
00 2 * * * sh /bin/bash/backup/backup.sh
```

Only difference is space after **bash** directory and sh command at the start of CRON job.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add username before your command like this for example :
1 * * * * root or username /usr/bin/php     /var/www/html/yourwebsite/yourscript.php

Comment: I was missing the username. Thanks!